# Outlook 2013 - Get own public key

Tags: ssh, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, public-key

I'm using Microsoft Outlook 2013 and have set up encryption/signing correctly.

Unfortunately I've lost my public key and would like to know how I can get it again using outlook (Note: I still have my private key).

The key should be in the format `ssh-rsa AAAA.....== rsa-key-20150101`

I'm already able to see my own certificate using 
"File > Trust Center > E-Mail Security > Import/Export > Export > Select Dialog > Click to view certificate"

However, the field "Pulic Key" only shows some Hex values and I don't know if this is even what I'm looking for, and what this values actually mean.

I really hope this question is not off-topic and someone around here can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can export your certificate to DER format (using "Copy to File..." button on the "Details" page of the certificate and selecting  "No, do not export the private key" and "DER encoded X.509 (.CER)" on the "Certificate Export Wizard"). And then you can extract its public key as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011572/convert-pem-key-to-ssh-rsa-format